# Pars code html with jsoup with android

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

i have this problem:

in this code html :

```
<li>
 <b> text1 </b>
  "text2"
</li>
```

using jsoup I managed to get the text of the tag 'li' but I get is 'text1' and 'text2', how do I take only 'text2'?

Comment: try `li > not:b` as a selector. Check http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax anyway.

Comment: What have you tried?
@kelmer, the syntax would be b:not(selector) for that option.

Comment: right, my mistake, that was directly out of my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the `ownText()` method of the Element class?

```
String html = "<li><b> text1 </b> \"text2\" </li>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

System.out.println(doc.select("li").first().ownText());
```

Will output:

```
"text2"
```